# how to unpack every n bits from a byte array into an integer array

Tags: python

`data` comes from a binary file, and I convert it to a byte_array using numpy as below:

```
byte_array = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Is there any convenient way to extract every n bits (8<=n<=20) from this `byte_array` then cast those n bits to an integer and store all the integers in an array?

The only way that I can think of is to go through the `byte_array` one by one, extract a full byte first, if the total bits extracted so far is less than n, extract the remaining bits, then concatenate with the first byte and form an output integer, store that integer to the output array.

For example, n = 12, byte_array[0:3] = 123, 99, 100

```
output_integer[0] = 123 | ((99&0xF)<<8) # bits 0..7 from 123 and bits 8..11 from the lower 4 bits of 99 
output_integer[1] = (99>>4) | (100<<4) # bits 0..3 from higher 4 bits of 99 and bits 4..11 from 100
```

Comment: Is the data in the file little endian or big endian?

Comment: @MarkRansom please see the comments in the example in the question

Comment: So you know that the example works properly then?

Comment: Yes. If I have to fix n to 12 and only work for a few numbers in the byte_array, this is how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generator for yielding the bits and use for example [`more_itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) to process the bit stream in n-chunks:

```py
from more_itertools import chunked

def get_bits(data):
    for b in data:
        yield from f'{bin(b)[2:]:0>8}'

data = b'0123456789'
n = 20
for bits in chunked(get_bits(data), n):
    print(int(''.join(bits), base=2))
```

In the above example, if `(r := len(data)*8 % n) != 0` then the last `bits` will be of length `r < n`. If that is undesired, you can either pad the bit stream beforehand on the left (i.e. at the start), which requires knowledge of its length, or use for example [`more_itertools.grouper`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.grouper) to pad it on the right (i.e. at the end).